# Equation Function `$` not registering in R-Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, equation, tinytex

I am currently learning the basics of R and I cannot figure out why, when I try to insert equations, I am getting the error message:

[image: trying to insert an equation into R Markdown]

I have installed and put in the library the packages tinyverse, DT, tinytex, here, knitr, and janitor for the rest of the notebook. I was trying to do troubleshooting yesterday and it said that tinytex could be wrong, so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and even tried tinytex::install_prebuild and that also did not work. I get the error message:

[image: after putting tinytex:: install_tinytex()]

Now if I do tinytex::tinytex_root(): I get "/Users/robinsonpa17/Library/TinyTex" which is weird because that is a different path then found in my folder (see below)[image: path to TinyTex in my computer]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

````
```{r}
$A=\pi * r^2$
```
````

Try using the equation without the chunk like in the following:

```
$A=\pi * r^2$
```

Put your cursor on the equation and you will see how it will be printed.

Comment: oh my goodness, thank you! I cannot believe that it was that simple, I was trying to figure it out for hours last night!

Comment: @PaigeRobinson, glad that helps! Sorry for the "hours last night!" :).